# Using an op-amp for the first time

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am a beginner at electronics and recently, I was learning op-amps. I approached to making a battery full charge circuit using LM311. But the problem is, I do not know which pins of the LM311 are connected where. Anybody would prepare a simple circuit for breadboard? The circuit for the IC, not the op-amp.

Comment: Google for "LM311 datasheet" - the datasheet should tell you more than you want to know about the LM311.  Datasheets for analog parts often include sample application circuits.  What do you mean by "The circuit for the IC, not the op-amp"?

Comment: When you get the LM311 datasheet you'll find that it is an analog comparator, not an op-amp.  The schematic symbols for op-amp and comparator are the same, but they are quite different in application and operation.  You might try a TL082 dual op-amp - they should be cheap and readily available.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the LM311 is a comparator.

If you're interested in op-amps, one that is easy to use and has relatively few bad habits is the LM324N. They're quite cheap, rugged, and can be run from a single supply or dual supply.

A lot of new new datasheets are missing the application circuits, but here is an old National Semiconductor [datasheet](http://www.eng.yale.edu/ee-labs/morse/compo/datasheets/LM324.pdf).

For example:

[image]

Comment: Clearly, I was mentioning the circuit including the pins of IC itself, not for the op-amp triangle. I was doing this for my battery charger circuit. My problem is not that I cannot create a battery charger circuit, but that I have failed in generating any output from the comparator.